What do the aliens in "A Quiet Place" use for a navigating sense?
Last night I finished the "A Quiet Place" trilogy (so far) with "A Quiet Place: Day One".
The blind aliens move with ferocious speed and precise agility. They navigate the clutter and chaos of a city street without tripping over random debris, fixtures, or each other. How? Super hearing doesn't help avoid a lamp post, climb stairs, or stand on a shoreline knowing there's water beyond.
Any crazy sensory method I can think of then fails to explain how an alien hunter can be literally cents away from a terrified human holding their breath (while possibly messing their pants), and not be able to detect their quarry.
If an answer was provided in the movies, I surely missed it. Reading the previous Q&A's here indicate a novelization connected with the films, so maybe the explanation is in there? Some of the members here have access to shooting scripts and such insider info.

There's no novelisation, as far as I'm aware. Allegedly there's a comic in the offing, but that's about it; https://bloody-disgusting.com/comics/3837182/idw-joining-forces-with-paramount-for-comics-based-on-smile-event-horizon-and-more/

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=J6RgS-blJ1g - no help here. Sound, apparently

The creatures use strong hearing to hunt, so we started with the idea of replicating actual animals like dolphins and bats that use echolocation to observe their surroundings. We felt it would have been too obvious to use the ‘clicks’ that those sort of animals use as the basis for the creatures, but we found that when you record the clicks made by a stun gun and slow them down, they create this disturbing, otherworldly sound that was perfect for the film. - https://amplify.nabshow.com/articles/the-extreme-sounds-of-silence-in-a-quiet-place-part-ii/

@Valorum - It works well because echolocation actually can help avoid large obstacles while giving a poor idea of texture and fine details, meaning that the creature standing in front of you probably has trouble figuring out whether you are a living thing or a bunch of dirt.

#Adamant   I once read that the hearing of some Cetaceans is tied to the visual cortex in their brains, enabling them to use echolocation data to form pictures of what is sensed.   And apparently echolocation can detect tiny objects since bats use it to catch flying insects.  Possibly the aliens use echolocation to navigate and regular hearing to locate prey.

@M.A.Golding - Echolocation is not just one thing. It depends on the wavelength of the sound, the acuity of the user's auditory processing, and more. For instance, humans can use echolocation, but might have trouble detecting small angles with it. One can expect a smaller animal with smaller prey, like a bat, to be better at detecting fine details. Particularly if the aliens use long-wavelength sounds at longer intervals, as Valorum's quote suggests, they could very easily have trouble with small details.

Also, an alien creature may have absolutely no context for what an edible creature on Earth should sound like (in terms of its physical appearance), except that if it is making noises that sound like moving, it is probably alive, so that is another obstacle. To such an alien, a human standing still might as well be a tree, even if its echolocation were good enough to make out the shape.

@Adamant Many species of bats ID and capture flying insects while flying themselves through the use of echolocation. So asserting that large objects only could be perceived via echolocation  is a bit inaccurate. Resolution will be tied closely to wavelength, so for ultrasound echolocation, millimeter resolution is realistic.

@Lexible - Did you read my comments?

@Adamant I did. "can help avoid large obstacles while giving a poor idea of texture and fine details" is inaccurate.

@Lexible - Perhaps only the first one? Your comment repeats information already given by another commenter and affirmed by me in the first sentence, and repeats something that I wrote in the third sentence. Equally important, what I wrote is a statement about feasibility of how one creature's echolocation could work in science fiction, thus the use of the word "can," not a universal statement about all kinds of echolocation, which I already clarified in those comments that you read.

@Lexible - So just remember, this is a point about the feasibility of a echolocating organism having a low-resolution perception, not about the feasibility of them having a high-resolution perception. That should help clarify things. In the case of these aliens, they are described as using noises that sound like a stun gun slowed down, which is not ultrasound (higher-frequency sounds than humans can hear), but rather low-wavelength (to judge from my listening to it) audible sound.

If you want to do some near zone length calculations given the frequency of the sound heard in the film and the diameter of the alien's vocal apparatus or whatever, you could, but bear in mind that the film is just meant to be artistically plausible, not to follow exact physics equations. Also bear in mind that a creature's auditory perception matters as well, which is completely up to writer fiat (e.g. the minimum, say, 0.2 μm resolution of a light microscope is at most one-tenth as small as a human can see under extremely optimal conditions).

@Adamant OOOh! That makes more sense. I see what you mean. Yes: surely echolocation does not have to be fine resolution.

Thanks for the in-depth discussion on echolocation-sonar. Obviously my knowledge of the particularities of such a sense was lacking. And I agree that we don't have to dive in to deep science. Just any explanation no matter how "comic booky" it might be.
